# Error TF31004 connecting VS2012 to TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am trying to setup a new connection to TFS with VS2012. Early on I was able to add my TFS server and, using the Microsoft Git Provider, clone a copy of the remote repository from within Visual Studio. Later, as I was fiddling with things in Team Explorer trying to find the branch I wanted to use, something broke. My local repository remains, but my connection to the remote repository was somehow corrupted, as evidenced with this error:

> TF31004: Unexpected error encountered while connecting to Team Foundation Server at http: //my.server.com:8080/tfs. Wait a few minutes and try again. If the problem persists, contact the server administrator <kbd>ok</kbd> <kbd>help</kbd>

Things I have tried to resolve this:

- Wait and try again (as the error message suggested).
- Restart Visual Studio.
- Reboot my machine.
- Reboot TFS server.
- Use system restore to revert back before I installed msysgit and Microsoft Git Provider, or had attempted to connect to the TFS server.
- Review the [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28vs.tfc.connecttotfs.unexpectederror%29&rd=true) for the error (see below).
- Search Stack Overflow (found one other related issue but did not seem to apply).
- Tried devenv /ResetSkipPkgs
- Tried devenv /setup
- Re-install [Team Explorer for VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656).
- Clear IE cookies (per [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8fb58cf-35fb-4653-8d00-93f51e7cda31/troubleshooting-connections-from-internet-explorer-visual-studio-to-team-foundation-service)).
- Clear TFS caches (per [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8fb58cf-35fb-4653-8d00-93f51e7cda31/troubleshooting-connections-from-internet-explorer-visual-studio-to-team-foundation-service)).

The help page offers these tidbits, but none of them seem likely given that I had, as I said, the connection working at one point:

- The version of Team Foundation running on the local computer does not match the version running on the Team Foundation Server server {name}.
- The server returned HTML content instead of XML content.
- The required Web service on the server could not be found.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: You said you're using the git provider - is this the Visual Studio Tools for Git extension? If so, have you got the latest version installed? Also are you connecting to the hosted TFService and a git repository on the server or are you using tf-git with TFVC?

Comment: Yes, the git provider is from Visual Studio for Git, version 0.9.5.0, installed yesterday. As to your last question, I am not quite sure but I believe it is the former (i.e. *not* using tf-git or TFVC, as I have not heard of those before :-).

Answer (score 13):

I have had an exactly the same problem.

My solution was to clear all the credentials in the Windows Vault (Credential Manager residing in the Control Panel).

I have no idea why the credentials did get messed up.

Comment: This worked for me, although I did not need to clear all the credentials in the Windows Vault.  All that I needed to do was remove the entry for the server I was trying to connect to.  I had reinstalled the server and kept the same name - that probably caused my credentials to get messed up

Comment: I had to clear two settings, one was for the git:http://tfs_server... and the other just the plain http://tfs_server.  Than I had to reboot Visual Studio.  After that, I was able to connect.  +1

Comment: @Bill Hey. I too have the same problem. Can you tell me where to change the settings from ??